# Nginx and Passenger deploy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I can only get the default nginx page to come up on my domain name.  I am pretty sure the error is either in the /etc/hosts file or the enginx.config file.

my /etc/hosts file is

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain    localhost
myip         server.mydomain.com  server
```

and nginx.config is:

```
    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name server.mydomain.com;
       root /whatever/pulic;
       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env production;
```

I don't get any errors in the log.  Incidentally I can run mongrel and on mydomain:3000 see the application there.

Answer (score 0):

In your /etc/hosts, you have

`123.45.67.78    server.domain.com    servername`

So in you nginx.conf you should have the line

`server_name  servername`

as you defined in the third column of your /etc/host. Make sure you don't still have the default nginx server block in your nginx.conf file, too, otherwise it might be taking priority (based on it's relative position).

Answer (score 0):

We just had this issue. The problem turned out to be that Nginx was using a different config file than we thought it was (possibly an issue with how it was compiled on the server?).

We discovered this by doing `nginx -t`, which lists the config file it's reading and tests the syntax. The one it said it was testing was not the one we expected.